# margin: 0 auto not working in a nested div with display flex properties

Tags: html, css, formatting, margin

I am Using a Nested div with display property set to flex i want the child divs to have margin auto to spread them evenly with equal spacing in a horizontal manner.
But the "margin: 0 auto;" is not working
the first div is a vertical strip or container which has display flex and direction row,
the child divs are same-sized cubical divs with display flex and flex-direction as column,
I wan using margin auto on the child divs but it is not working.

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.panel-opt {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 114px;
  height: 114px;
  border: solid 0.5px #707070;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-opt opt-1">
    <div class="opt-num">
      <span class="opt-num-span">125</span>
    </div>
    <div class="opt-svg">

    </div>
    <span class="opt-span">Orders</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-opt opt-2">
    <div class="opt-num">
      <span class="opt-num-span">125</span>
    </div>
    <div class="opt-svg">

    </div>
    <span class="opt-span">Orders</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-opt opt-3">
    <div class="opt-num">
      <span class="opt-num-span">125</span>
    </div>
    <div class="opt-svg">

    </div>
    <span class="opt-span">Orders</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-opt opt-4">
    <div class="opt-num">
      <span class="opt-num-span">125</span>
    </div>
    <div class="opt-svg">

    </div>
    <span class="opt-span">Orders</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove width: fit-content;

Answer (score 0):

just remove `width: fit-content;` and add `justify-content: space-around;` in your parent div `.panel` .
Like  this:

```
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 30px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

here's the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/khushboo097/qg92x3am/13/

Comment: with the "space-around" property you end up with a gap on both sides of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the `justify-content` property to `space-between`. This will space
   the panel elements evenly within the parent container.
2. Set the `flex-basis` property on the panels to `100%` to give them a fluid width. This will cause the panels to stretch their width to fill the available space. Result is all panels have same width.
3. Set the `max-width` property on the panels to whatever you want.
4. Use the `nth-child` selector to select all elements but the first child, and give it a margin-left to act as a gutter.

```css
.panel {
  /* space items evenly within container */
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.panel-opt {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* make width fluid so elements dont overflow */
  flex-basis: 100%;
  /* optionally set max-width of elements */
  max-width: 114px;
  height: 114px;
  border: solid 0.5px #707070;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* select all panels except the first one */
.panel-opt:not(:first-child) {
  /* set left margin which will work as a gutter */
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-opt opt-1">
    <div class="opt-num">
      <span class="opt-num-span">125</span>
    </div>
    <div class="opt-svg">

    </div>
    <span class="opt-span">Orders</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-opt opt-2">
    <div class="opt-num">
      <span class="opt-num-span">125</span>
    </div>
    <div class="opt-svg">

    </div>
    <span class="opt-span">Orders</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-opt opt-3">
    <div class="opt-num">
      <span class="opt-num-span">125</span>
    </div>
    <div class="opt-svg">

    </div>
    <span class="opt-span">Orders</span>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-opt opt-4">
    <div class="opt-num">
      <span class="opt-num-span">125</span>
    </div>
    <div class="opt-svg">

    </div>
    <span class="opt-span">Orders</span>
  </div>
</div>
```